# Misunderstanding about SQL Server floats and the return of SQLCMD

Tags: sql-server, precision, sqlcmd

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax), a double in SQL Server is a float with `n = 53` (8 bytes storage, 15 digits precision).

However, when I am running `SQLCMD` to get a row from my DB, the result does not return a 15 digits precision double/float, but a 17 digits one.

For example: `0.58974358999999998`

The decimal is 17 digits long, why not 15 as specified in the documentation?

Edit: this is my SQL query:

```
SELECT TOP(1) * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE object_key = '28499'
```

Comment: What SQL are you actually running here to get your result?

Comment: @Larnu Added into the question.

Comment: ... We can't actually run that SQL, so it doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: The fact that you wanted actual data was not specified. As a consequence I thought you were requiring my query because I may have done a mistake/something that causes the problem described. I cannot give your the data as it comes from a company database. I will provide you with a sample as soon as I have time for that (in something like 3 hours) @Larnu

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The number you are seeing is **rounded**.

Under the hood SQL Server does not store floats as decimal digits. Because  your number is between `0.5` and `1` it will be stored like:

```
2^(-1) * (1 + 0 * 1/2 + 0*1/4 + ..... + [0 or 1] * 1/(2^52) )
```

What is important, is the precision of your number will be stored as slices such as `1/(2^53)`, which is: `1.1102230246251565404236316680908e-16`. Then it will be rounded. SQL Server, SSMS, and SQLCMD are free to decide how to round this number when displaying or converting. For example, they changed the rules for how it is rounded to decimal during conversion in version 2016.

Summarizing, real and float numbers are never stored as exact numbers. Rather, they are always a rounded result of binary division. You can find more about internal storage at Wikipedia:

> [Double-precision_floating-point_format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)